# java.util.List subList(int,int) behavior in ArrayList and LinkedList

Tags: java, list

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
When reading about `java.util.List` methods and testing `sublist(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` I found the following results:

- when using an `ArrayList` which is backed by an array, modifying structurally the result of calling sublist() will throw an UnsupportedOperationException.
- when using a `LinkedList` which is backed by nodes with links between, modifying structurally the result of calling `sublist()` will NOT throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Is it because adding an element into an `ArrayList` will shift all the elements from the right of the position where is being added and this is an operation which affects the array outside the `sublist()` bounds while adding an element into a `LinkedList` means only creating a new node and only link it into the list by modifying its neighbours node links?

Comment: Please show us a short self-contained snippet of code that demonstrates the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the `subList()` from an `ArrayList` does not throw `UnsupportedOperationException` - the following works fine:

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    List sub = list.subList(1, 2);
    sub.add("d");
```

Comment: I was using Arrays.asList, there the confusion. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` supports adding elements in the middle of the list with the method `add(int index, E element)`, just as a `LinkedList` does. And in either case the sublist's bounds will be affected, that's not a problem.